# Adding nested children inside parent and nesting should be equal to number of elements in an array

Tags: php, recursion, nested-loops

I have to generate a nested array of parent and children. Basically, I have a list as below.

```
$changeLog = array(
    array("data1" => "value1"),
    array("data2" => "value2"),
    array("data3" => "value3")
)
```

For each value of `$changeLog` I have to add a nested child in an array. So for instance, I have 3 values in changeLog the expected result should be as follows:

```
$finalResult = array(
        "parent1" => "value1",
        "child" => array(
           "parent2" => "value2",
           "child" => array(
                 "parent3" => "value3",
                 "child" => array(
                      "parent4" => "value4"
                  )
           )
        )
    )
```

So, in short, for each value (that is basically an array, I have to fetch some values from that array that will be used in nested child) in `$changeLog` a nested child will be added. I tried to do it using recursion and in for loop too. But I am completely lost how to proceed with it. Can someome give me a hint how we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a data structure as simple as possible. 
Also working with big nested arrays is always complicated.

I would propose to change format of $finalResult variable to the following(using some kind of tree structure without multidimensional array):

```
$finalResult = [
    "1" => "value1",
    "1.2" => "value2",
    "1.2.3" => "value3",
    "1.2.3.4" => "value4"
];
```

In this case array key "1" is unique ID and path of the parent1.

Array key "1.2" is unique path of the parent2, "2" is ID from parent2.

Array key "1.2.3" is unique path of the parent3, "3" is ID from parent3.

Array key "1.2.3.4" is unique path of the parent4, "4" is ID from parent4.

and so on...

In this case you can simply access elements, you can sort array by keys.

And f.ex. array key "1.2.3.4" show you that it's parent4 with ID "4" and it a child of parents with IDs "1", "2" and "3"

In array key "1.2.3.4" the last number after last dot is unique ID, everything before the last dot show you IDs of all parents.